# Convert JPEG or PNG to SVG format on VB.net/C# or Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, vb.net, cordova, ios5

I would like to convert a PNG or JPEG file to SVG. But I can't find anything on how to do it. The thing is I'm using devexpress reports to export it to image so the format can either be .jpg or .png. Now what I want is to convert it to SVG so that the image will still be in a better quality when passing it through Javascript and finally to Objective-C.

To explain a bit further.

I have a service which is coded using VB.net. This is server side; client side is Javascript and HTML: I'm using Phonegap to bridge Objective-C. What I'm doing really is creating a plugin which would pass a URL from Javascript and have Objective-C catch the url, then load it as an image and pass it to the ePOS SDK to print as an image.

What I noticed is that when I'm exporting the report using devexpress as a png, the image gets pixelated and a bit grainy because I'm scaling the image to make it bigger to fill the thermal paper (80mm). That's why instead of PNG I want it in SVG to preserve the quality of the image.

My question is where should I convert the image? On the server side or in Objective-C? And how will I do such a daunting task? I was thinking of doing it in Objective-C, but I think it is much better to convert it on the server side. What do you think?

Also is it possible to convert .png or .jpeg to a .svg file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on the server side with ImageMagick, but I think that since you'll be converting a bitmap image to vector graphics, you'll just get the same low-quality crap. Can you export your reports to PDF or another vector graphics format?

Comment: i was actually going for the pdf format but i think it would slow my application since i will be forced to take snapshots of every page then have it printed.